# Побитовый сдвиг вправо на отрицательных числах

Tags: системы-счисления

```
-7 >> 1
```

Получается -4.

Было `1000 0111`, двинули вправо. Вроде должно получиться `1000 0011`. Как так вышло, что получилось `1000 0100`? Что я упустил?
Для простоты пусть будет `byte`.

Comment: а почему вы решили что -7 именно так записывается?) Прочитайте про дополнительный код.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вообще-то, -7 в дополнительном коде будет не `1000 0111`, а `1111 1001`. После сдвига вправо получается `1111 1100`, что равно -4. Все правильно, компьютер не ошибся.

PS осторожнее с такими сдвигами. В языке C++ они дают UB.

Comment: сейчас будет вопрос, почему размножается знаковый бит и как этого избежать.

Comment: А что конкретно здесь UB?

Comment: @Flowneee битовый сдвиг по стандарту только в unsigned применим.

Comment: @Flowneee сдвиг отрицательного числа

Comment: @PavelMayorov и pavel спасибо (жаль нельзя нормально 2х участников проставить в сообщении нормально)

Comment: @pavel не будет :)